# WPF Mvvm solving order of event fired and view created

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvmcross

I am just starting with WPF and MVVMCross, so just need your help guys :) I will give you short example of my issue:

I have ContactViewModel, and in that VM i am subscribed on some ovent, for example Connected event which is fired when i go from offline to online. But, that event is fired before my VM os created, so i will never be notified about it in scope of that VM.

I encountered this issue and i wonder how these kind of problems are solved in Clients world, how you can orcestrate/store/save/not miss, all these events you need, and which obviously happens before your view model is alive?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use a ConnectionService which will hold the current state for IsConnected and inject it into every class which needs to know the connection state

Answer (score 1):

In this specific instance you could ping an external web server and if it works then you're online.

In a more general sense, message queues are often used for situations where there's a mismatch between event published and target/subscriber action. That can include throttling processing as well as when the subscriber just isn't run.  Message queues can be persisted to disk so you have a log of events available for however long you like even when your front end app hasn't been run. 
But this process can be with or without a full service bus implementation. You could read at length on service bus.

If the event is specific to the client you need a windows service which loads on startup to monitor the event(s) and write to a message queue. When you run your app that would either have a process starts up which can read the queue and be switched to firing events of it's own. Your viewmodel would get a reference to that ( often by dependency injection as Sir Rufo suggested ) and the data is available via a method.